# Normal Class extend to another abstract class

Tags: java

```
public abstract class A {
    abstract void polo();
}

class B extends A {
}
```

My doubt is if I give `abstract` keyword in class `B` means it wont shows anything

```
abstract class B extends A {
}
```

Why its not showing the message here to implement methods in class A - this is my doubt.

If I didn't give abstract keyword means class `B` indicates like this

> The type B must implement the inherited abstract method A.polo()

What's wrong with that one. Can abstract class extend another abstract class or not.

Comment: Yes it can. Seems you need to read [that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a non-abstract class extends an abstract class, it must implement all abstract methods, in your case class B must implement polo()

If you make class B abstract, then you don't have to. But in this case you can't create an instance of B and the classes that extends B should implement polo

Comment: Now i created a normal class C and extends B , it implements both polo and one more abstract method in B  as display that also implemented in C and it shows annotation as override polo and display .

Answer (score 0):

You can extend an abstract class, but you must decide what the new one will do about the abstract methods. You can choose to implement all those methods, so the abstract keyword won't be required. You can also implement some or none of the methods, but you must mark the class as abstract.
Depending of the business logic, you may put the abstract methods into an Interface that required classes will implement.

Answer (score 0):

if B is abstract
       not mandatory to implement the method
       but you can implement the method or left implementation for child class

but if B is not abstract
it is mandatory you implement the abstract method

Answer (score 0):

One handy trick I use in this situation is to make class B non abstract to start with. I then use the IDE to generate the over-rides for all the abstract methods and then afterwards I make class B abstract and then go through the overridden methods and decide for each one whether to implement them or leave them abstract at this level too.